# Angular2 (Typescript) with STS

Tags: angularjs, spring, typescript, angular, spring-tool-suite

How to make Angular2 code written in typescript run in spring-tool-suite? 
I can run the Angular 2 code written in javascript in spring-tool-suite, but in case of typescript, I am facing a lot of problems in the form of:
1. NOT FOUND errors

I am attaching a screen shot for the error[image]

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting (`404` on javascript files) points that the backend (web server) is not configured correctly.

## Potential Fix

Give webpack a go so that you only need to load a single `bundle.js` instead of having to over configure a web server backend.

Comment: have you tried integrating angular 2 with spring(STS)?